# Using puppet with terraform

Tags: linux, puppet, devops, terraform

I want to create an AWS instance using Terraform and run a Puppet module inside it. I have tried many modules from github and nothing seems to work. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 5):

The way you basically have to do this is install puppet locally with a `remote-exec` provisioner and then either do an `apply` or `agent` execution. First, setup your instance `resource` like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance_name" {
  ...

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    script = "puppet.sh"
  }
}
```

Swap out `aws_instance` for a different cloud provider if/when not using AWS (Azure, DO, GCE, etc.) Then, use the script to install Puppet, execute `apply` or the `agent`, and then uninstall Puppet (if you are not activelly managing the instance afterward, which you likely would not be in the cloud).

```
#!/bin/sh
# debian family example; swap out 'apt' and package names where necessary
# prep puppet
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ruby -y
sudo gem install --no-document puppet
# apply puppet
sudo puppet apply manifest.pp
# remove puppet
sudo gem uninstall -aIx
sudo apt-get remove ruby -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

There are some variations on this. For example, you can `curl` against your Puppet Master or subscribe to the Puppetlabs package repository to install Puppet AIO. You can also do `puppet agent -t` afterward instead of a `puppet apply`. This may be preferable as transferring your modules over to be used with `apply` can be onerous.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use case but using ansible instead of puppet, we use null_resource along with local-exec.

```
resource "null_resource" "lvm_housekeeping" {
  triggers {
    ebs_volume_ids = "${join(",", aws_volume_attachment.instance_ebs_attachment.*.volume_id)}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ANSIBLE_CONFIG=$HOME/'${var.ansible_repo_location}'/ansible.cfg ansible-playbook -u ec2-user -e target=all -i '${join(",",aws_instance.my_instance.*.private_ip)}, ' $HOME/'${var.ansible_repo_location}'/main.yml"

    on_failure = "continue"
  }
}
```