# How to make puppet and terraform work together?

Tags: azure, terraform, puppet

I am creating a virtual machine in terraform that will appear in Azure.  Broadly speaking, once that's created how can I tell puppet that the virtual machine exists and to do the basic config steps?  I have puppet with the commands I want it to run when a virtual machine is made.  Can I tell it to look for a resource with a name?  I am pretty clueless and have not been able to find much information on how in code the two work together.

Comment: With [null_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource). You will have access to runtime attributes of terraform outputs which you feed into above resource. People use it heavily with ansible..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using puppet with terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461884/using-puppet-with-terraform)

Comment: Note that five years later `cloud-init` becomes more relevant than `remote-exec`.

Comment: I'm not sure so I can't tell it in the puppet code what to look for?  I tell it in terraform

Comment: I'm mainly unsure. I have a file linux-vm that makes the vm, but I am not sure of where to put this stuff for puppet

Comment: If you're simply trying to apply various resources, I would suggest using puppet-bolt.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing it on a cloud infrastructure I'd install the agent, either from a local repo or downloading and installing from the Puppet downloads site https://puppet.com/try-puppet/puppet-enterprise/download/.
Then once the agent was installed I'd run `puppet config set server <your puppet server>`
Within 30 minutes the agent should run and contact the puppet server.
If you've configured autosign https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/ssl_autosign.html then the server will accept the certificate request and start managing the node.